# error loop with while and foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

I should like to display this table under

```
September 2013
- 14/09/2013 | 14:30 | Football | League | Paris - Berlin
- 14/09/2013 | 19:30 | Volley | Cup | Paris - Barcelona
- 25/09/2013 | 12:00 | Football | Amical | Paris - Bordeaux 
October 2013
- 5/10/2013 | 15: 00 | Cup | Paris - Londres
```

This is my code

```
$dateQuery = mysql_query("SELECT matches.id, date_debut, date_fin, matches.score, sports.title AS sport, clubs1.title AS recevant, clubs2.title AS visiteur, competitions.title AS competition, matches.description, sexes.title AS sexe
    FROM matches
    INNER JOIN sexes ON sexes.id = matches.sexe_id
    INNER JOIN sports ON sports.id = matches.sport_id
    INNER JOIN clubs AS clubs1 ON clubs1.id = matches.recevant_id
    INNER JOIN clubs AS clubs2 ON clubs2.id = matches.visiteur_id
    INNER JOIN competitions ON competitions.id = matches.competition_id
        WHERE CURRENT_DATE()<=date_debut
        ORDER BY date_debut ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($dateQuery)){
   print '<b>'.$tIndexed[$row['date_debut'] ][ $row['sport'] ][]=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['date_debut'])).'</b><br />';

foreach($tIndexed as $sDate => $tIndexedDate){

    foreach($tIndexedDate as $sEvenement => $tIndexedEvenement){

        foreach($tIndexedEvenement as $sTexte){
            $sTexte = $row['recevant'].'-'.$row['visiteur'];
          print date("H:i",strtotime($row['date_debut'])).' | ' .$row['sport'].' | '.$row['competition'].' | '.$sTexte.' <br />';
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The wrong result display

`14-09-2013
14:30 | Football | Championnat de France | IOS ORLEANS-CSSM PARIS 
14-09-2013
19:30 | Football | Championnat de France | CSSM PARIS-ASLS NANCY 
19:30 | Football | Championnat de France | CSSM PARIS-ASLS NANCY 
21-09-2013
15:00 | Football | Championnat de France | CSS RENNES-CSSM PARIS 
15:00 | Football | Championnat de France | CSS RENNES-CSSM PARIS 
15:00 | Football | Championnat de France | CSS RENNES-CSSM PARIS 
28-09-2013
19:30 | Football | Championnat de France | CSSM PARIS-CSS RENNES 
19:30 | Football | Championnat de France | CSSM PARIS-CSS RENNES 
19:30 | Football | Championnat de France | CSSM PARIS-CSS RENNES 
19:30 | Football | Championnat de France | CSSM PARIS-CSS RENNES`

I hope you can help to me to resolve this problem.

Thanks you

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: He wants the results displaying as he described at the beginning of the question

Comment: change the starting query to  SELECT distinct(matches.id)

Comment: no, the display is always wrong

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$dateQuery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT matches.id, date_debut, date_fin, matches.score,     sports.title AS sport, clubs1.title AS recevant, clubs2.title AS visiteur, competitions.title AS competition, matches.description, sexes.title AS sexe
FROM matches
INNER JOIN sexes ON sexes.id = matches.sexe_id
INNER JOIN sports ON sports.id = matches.sport_id
INNER JOIN clubs AS clubs1 ON clubs1.id = matches.recevant_id
INNER JOIN clubs AS clubs2 ON clubs2.id = matches.visiteur_id
INNER JOIN competitions ON competitions.id = matches.competition_id
    WHERE CURRENT_DATE()<=date_debut
    ORDER BY date_debut ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```